# How to remove extra space between tabs in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

I've implemented `TabBar()` inside my `AppBar()`.

Now, there is extra space between tabs. I'm running it on Chrome (web). I've tried to add zero padding to the `indicatorPadding`, `labelPadding` and `padding` parameters inside `TabBar()` but nothing shrinks the tab bar items.

So how can I reduce the space between them? Here is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: height,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: TabBar(
    indicatorColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
    labelColor: Colors.black,
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 12,
    ),
    tabs: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: const Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
          text: "Home",
          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: const Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.groups_rounded),
          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          text: "My Network",
        ),
      ),
      const Tab(
        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.work_rounded,
          // size: 20,
        ),
        text: "Jobs",
      ),
      const Tab(
        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        icon: Icon(Icons.message_rounded),
        text: "Messaging",
      ),
      const Tab(
        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_rounded),
        text: "Notification",
      ),
    ],
  ));
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Make sure you set padding to zero for tabs, label and indicator.

```
TabBar(
   indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
   isScrollable: true,
   tabs: categoriesWidgets,
   padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   indicatorWeight: 4,
 )
```

Comment: `labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` it was what was missing for me, thanks for you answer and time.

Answer (score 12):

TabBar(
...
tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
)

Comment: This is very helpful with new flutter version

Comment: yes i have the same issue but after this i fixed it

Answer (score 8):

I'm able to find the solution to this.

Just by adding `isScrollable: true` parameter to `TabBar()` all tabs shrink to one side.

Without setting `isScrollable: true` all tabs items were taking all the space they have in the given widget.

End Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Change the value for the property `labelPadding` to adjust the padding of tabs.
For no padding, `labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make the space around them (at right and left) where tabs closer to each other. try to add symmetric padding like this for the tabbar:

`TabBar(... padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),tabs:[...])`

Comment: I don't want to add space/padding I just want to remove the extra space you can see between 2 red and green tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try `labelPadding` parameter. Giving it a value of `0` should take care of the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can give width attribute to the container

```
 Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width:2.0
        child: const Tab(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
          text: "Home",
          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        ),
      ),
```