# Can't remove space between tab bar buttons in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I wanna remove extra space between tab bar elements! I have tried several such as editing different padding properties of the `TabBar` widget and set them to `EdgeInsets.zero` but none of them worked for me.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
Material(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.h,
                    color: AppColors.kBackgroundColor,
                    child: TabBar(
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h, bottom: 10.h),
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: AppColors.kPrimaryGradientColor),
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50.h,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: AppColors.kPrimaryGradientColor,
                                    width: 1)),
                            child: const Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Semaine"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: AppColors.kPrimaryGradientColor,
                                    width: 1)),
                            child: const Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Mois"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: AppColors.kPrimaryGradientColor,
                                    width: 1)),
                            child: const Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Toujours"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think its relavant to this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69356773/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-tabs-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 3, // Define the number of tabs
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black, // Change the tab text color to black
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: "Semaine",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Mois",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Toujours",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                // Add the content for each tab here
                // For example:
                Center(
                  child: Text("Semaine Tab Content", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Mois Tab Content", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("Toujours Tab Content", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually do not want to display the default design of the tab bar. I want to do something a bit different by making giving tabs heads rounded shape and all! The code your provided solves the spacing problem but using the default tab bar design, not using this design!

Comment: you can customize the design as you need with the code I provided